# Is the gravity reading from a Tilt Hydrometer adjusted for temperature?

Tags: hydrometer

The reason I ask is threefold.

1. I watched my gravity readings go up from 1.039 to 1.043 as I cooled my wort before I pitched.
2. I noticed in the System page of my TiltPI, it says `SG 15C/59F (default)`
3. When I cold crash, the gravity readings go up. When I enter the temperature and gravity reading in a [hydrometer temperature adjustment calculator](https://www.brewersfriend.com/hydrometer-temp/), the gravity is the same as before the cold crash.

It seems beyond reason that this device would need to be adjusted for temperature, since it is both a hydrometer and thermometer, but that appears to be the case.

Comment: I searched around on the internet and on their FAQs. I believe TILT doesn't do this automatically (and probably shouldn't). It seems to have two independent sensors providing data. The good news is- this could probably be solved in the TiltPI UI. My advice is file a feature request to Tilt for TiltPi to have an Adjusted gravity option.

Comment: Also.. I've never used the TiltPi system (yet!) but if it's like other Pi systems you could probably modify it to do..whatever you want. It usually requires a little technical know-how. If you don't have the skills..you can usually trade a few homebrews to someone who does ;)

Comment: Dang. I had always assumed (since it produces values for both Temp and SG) it would correct.  I use  Beersmith which imports the Tilt data, but now it seems I need to fiddle with the values after they are imported.  Disappointed.  However, it does explain some odd values I have gotten now and then.

Answer (score 1):

I know this ? is a bit old, but I just got some info in this regard directly from the manufacturer.  Here's what they say...

1. Between 55°F and 90°F -- no adjustment is needed.  The casing of the Tilt and the air inside it contract/expand at the same rate as the wort.  As a result, in that temp range, any adjustment would be negligible.
2. Outside that range, the Tilt expands/contracts ***more*** rapidly than the wort itself.  As a result the adjustments would be opposite those of a normal hydrometer (i.e., falsely gives a low reading for cold wort, and falsely gives a high reading for hot wort)...
3. Below 55°F: adjust by *adding* 1 SG pt (0.001) for every 10°F below 55°F.
4. Above 90°F: adjust by *subtracting* 1 SG pt for every 10°F above 90°F.

Hope this is helpful.  Good to know that no adjustment is needed at normal fermentation temps.

Comment: Yeah, this simply doesn't match my empirical data of 50+ batches. In my experience, it behaves like a normal hydrometer, calibrated at 59F. You can largely ignore any calibration if you are using a consistent temperature. However, if you are ramping or crashing, you will get incorrect results without calibrating the reading to the temperature. I think you got a hold of someone blowing smoke :-)

Comment: It is correct in the direction, but not near enough in the quantity of the adjustment. Just use a standard adjustment for temp and it will be accurate.

Answer (score -1):

Beer, like most liquids becomes less dense at higher temperatures but this effect also depends upon the alcohol content so it would be hard to reliably calibrate out.
In reality I would strongly advise that hydrometers based on the tilt principle are great for showing *variations* in SG but are not particularly reliable as an accurate measure of *absolute* gravity. Therefore they are best used as a means of keeping track of the progress of a fermentation from day-to-day, but when it comes to establishing the final gravity of your brew it's best to use a hydrometer.